# Disable automatic screen turn-off during call

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calls, screen, proximity-sensor

I use Gingerbread.

My Android phone has feature, that turns off display during call when I put the phone to my ear. However, the sensor is probably over-sensitive in my device, so it often turns off during call even when I don't keep it next to my face.

This is an issue if I want to use keyboard during call when the screen turns off. **Can I disable this feature?**

Comment: Screen turn off is managed by proximity sensor, so you will have to disable that. There seem to be some applications that will help you do that. Check   
Screebl Lite - Save Power!

Answer (score 5):

Plug in a headset. It's the only answer!

Comment: I've tried that. Even with headset/earphones plugged in, or set to speaker, the screen blanks (black) within a few seconds from when a call connects. If I press the power button, the screen will come back active but only for a few seconds, only enough time to press 1 or 2 keys (sometimes 3). It's "impossible" to check voicemail.

Answer (score 4):

In gingerbread 2.3.6, you can turn it off in Call Settings>Additional Settings then uncheck the "Turn on proximity Sensor". 
Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screehshot]

Comment: Option not present in 5.1

Answer (score 2):

I have v. 6.0.1. I contacted support with this problem, since I do not have any proxy setting. Go to settings - > apps -> phone or dial app -> memory -> clear cache and memory and restart your device. This worked for me. Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: I think that is "storage", not "memory".

Comment: doesn't help for those of us with hardware problems :|

Answer (score 1):

In Gingerbread you can find it in Advanced Settings in the Call Settings: go to Settings -> Calls-> Advanced. I'm not sure where exactly but it's where you have the options of call waiting, etc.

Comment: That's extremely dependent on the ROM, looking here on GB 2.3.7, that does not exist! What ROM is that are you referring to?

Comment: thats 2.3.6! im sure its somewhere there. or press options in the keypad screen and check everywhere in preferences!

Comment: *check everywhere in preferences*.... hummm... could do better than that! Enclose a screenshot of it, and should have stated GB 2.3.6 in your answer ...

Comment: For those who found this answer, and are looking for the answer on a newer android version, I found this on my Samsung Galaxy S 3, running Android 4.1.1, this is how I turned off that feature. Enter the dialer (the "Phone" icon", as if you wanted to make a call). Bring up the menu, and click "Call Settings". Uncheck "Auto Screen off during calls"

Answer (score 1):

Use ["Screen On Call" app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vorlan.screenoncall.free) to keep screen on during call. There is no need to turn proximity sensor off. It will keep working and if you move you phone to your ear, screen will go off, but if you keep it on the table or away from any blocking objects, screen will stay on, so you will be able to use keypad to punch more numbers or for whatever reason you want screen to stay on.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free app named Screebl, that will keep your phone on during a call. In fact, you will have to physically shut your phone off/place it in standy, after you install this app by tapping the on/off button on a Samsung Galaxy Proclaim 2.3.6 Gingerbread OS.